# How to fix "Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left" in Matlab parfor job on AWS cluster

Tags: matlab, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I started a batch job on an AWS cluster which unfortunately finished with an error after around 2h. Before submitting the job, I run it on a local cluster with reduced loop iterations where it worked fine. The error message was:

```
Task with properties:

ID: 1
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:14
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 50s

Error: All workers aborted during execution of the parfor loop.
Error Stack: parallel_function (line 607)
generic_adaptation (line 75)
Warnings: List warnings
Task with properties:

ID: 2
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 3
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:23
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 42s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 4
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 5
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 6
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:23
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 40s

Error: Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
The worker MATLAB exited or was stopped during task evaluation. MATLAB ended with exit status 9.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 7
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 8
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 9
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 10
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 11
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 12
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 13
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:23
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 42s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 14
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 15
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
Task with properties:

ID: 16
State: finished
Function: @parallel.internal.cluster.executeScript
Parent: Job 5
StartDateTime: 11-Apr-2019 10:45:22
Running Duration: 0 days 1h 42m 43s

Error: The parallel job was cancelled because the task with ID 2 terminated abnormally for the following reason:
Cannot rerun task because there are no rerun attempts left (The task has no rerun attempts left.).
Original cancel message:
Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.
Warnings:
```

As everything did work on a local cluster on my PC, I suspect that the code itself is fine but the reason for the error is somewhere else (maybe the connection to the AWS EC2 cluster or an internally error on the cluster?)

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow, Fololo! I think you need to look closer at that `Unexpected error in PostJobEvaluate - MATLAB will now exit and restart.`. That seems to be what actually caused your job to bomb out. `PostJobEvaluate` doesn't seem to be part of the Matlab Parallel Server. Is it part of your code? Any chance you have some log files, or a stack trace from the error? Keeping log files is key to debugging distributed/remote stuff.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your reply. The server shut down after the error as there were no more jobs in the job queue and as the log files were not persistend, I think they were deleted. However, I contacted the matlab support and they were able to restore some log files. It seems that the total amount of requested storage overshot the available one on the chosen instance. Hence, matlab suggested to eighter decrease the number of workers or to switch to a storage optimized instance.

Comment: Matlab suggested to search for log files under: 
`/var/log/mjs/` or `/var/log/mdce`; the "home" directory of the failed worker